# Same version of clang giving different results on different OS's

Tags: c++, clang, homebrew, msys2

I have clang 15.0.7 installed with brew in MacOS and the same version installed with MSYS2 in Windows 10.

When I compile the following program:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
  std::filesystem::path p("/some/path");
  std::string s(p);
}
```

using `clang++ -std=c++20 test.cpp` I get no compilation errors on MacOS, but in windows it gives:

```
test.cpp:6:15 error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')
  std::string s(p);
              ^ ~
[more errors]
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::filesystem::path::value_type` is `wchar_t` on Windows and `char` elsewhere.

Hence, `std::filesystem::path` has a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/native) to `std::wstring` on Windows and to `std::string` elsewhere (who even thought this was a good idea?!).

Call `.string()` to get `std::string` in a "portable" manner.

On Windows, make sure to test UTF-8 support on all standard library flavors you're interested in (MSVC STL, GCC's libstdc++, Clang's libc++). I remember that at least on MSVC you had to enable UTF-8 support with a locale, or use `std::u8string`.